# VB.NET XPathDocument.CreateNavigator throws "debuggerDisplayProxy" error

Tags: xml, vb.net, xpath, ms-office, xpathnavigator

I'm new to this and working from a tutorial. I have a variation on the following code:

```
Dim xDoc As XPathDocument
Dim xNav As XPathNavigator

xDoc = New XPathDocument("xxxxxxx.xml")
xNav = xDoc.CreateNavigator()
```

However, "CreateNavigator" returns: *'debuggerDisplayProxy' is a type and cannot be used as an expression.*

I've Googled and searched and found nothing (although I'm not really sure what to look for). This seems like something basic and it's stopping me from continuing with a lot of other stuff that I know works!

Answer (score 4):

It is not a real error, the debugger has a problem with the attribute on the class:

```
<DebuggerDisplay("{debuggerDisplayProxy}")> _
Public MustInherit Class XPathNavigator
    '' etc..
End Class
```

The name is spelled wrong, it should be "DebuggerDisplayProxy" with a capital D.  For some reason this only goes wrong in VB.NET, this isn't a problem in C# so that's probably why it hasn't been fixed yet.  Just keep clicking on the [+] to see the internal members of the object.  And keep going, there's nothing wrong with your code.

I filed this as a bug report at [Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/741440/xpathnavigator-has-bad-debuggerdisplayattribute).

Comment: Oh, the irony.  They ignored the bug report and paid dearly for that later.  [Now fixed in .NETCore v2.1](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/24360)