# cs0103 the name'debuggerDisplayProxy' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

I'm trying to construct a soap envelope to send data and, when I instantiate XmlDocument object, I'm getting this error "cs0103 the name'debuggerDisplayProxy' does not exist in the current context". I don't know what it is or how to solve it. I searched on the web and didn't find anything useful. Could you help, please?

Below, is the code where I try to do the envelope:

```
private static System.Xml.XmlDocument CreateSoapEnvelope(string xml)
{
    var soapEnvelope = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();

    soapEnvelope.LoadXml(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
                     <soap:Envelope 
                   xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" 
                   xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" 
                   xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"">
                     <soap:Body>
                   <HelloWorld3 xmlns="" 
                    http://localhost:52700/api/SOAPService/PostObject"">"
                    + xml + 
                    "</HelloWorld3></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>");
    return soapEnvelope;

}
```

Below, the error:

[image]

Comment: This code doesn't mention `debuggerDisplayProxy`. Where exactly does it give that error?

Comment: Sorry. The error appears in the variable, when I run debug mode. You can see it in this print I'm going to attach.

Comment: Looks like it's a debugger bug: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/24360 I suggest you edit your question to make it clear this is *only* an issue in the debugger - at the moment until you look at the image, it sounds like it's a compile-time error.

Comment: This is an error produced by the debugger itself, it has trouble displaying the content of the XmlDocument object.  It is a known bug in .NETCore v2.0, the bug report [is here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/24360).  Fixed in v2.1, but I can't recommend using it yet.  Try to work around it with Debug.Print() if you need to know the content of the XmlDocument, otherwise just keep motoring.

Comment: Please add code, errors and data as **text** ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing.  Images should only be used, *in addition to text in code format*, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: Heh, I reported this bug [six years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10525901/17034).  They ignored it :(

Comment: Thanks everyone. I decided to work around like Hans sujested. I'm sorry for the bad quality of this first post. I'll have your considerations in mind next time.